# Rails3: Nested model - child validates_with method results in "NameError - uninitialized constant [parent]::[child]"

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested, nameerror

Consider the following parent/child relationship where Parent is 1..n with Kids (only the relevant stuff here)...

```
 class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

   # !EDIT! - was missing this require originally -- was the root cause!
   require "Kid"

   has_many :kids, :dependent => :destroy, :validate => true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids

   validates_associated :kids

 end

 class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :parent

   # for simplicity, assume a single field:  @item
   validates_presence_of :item, :message => "is expected"

 end
```

The validates_presence_of methods on the Kid model works as expected on validation failure, generating a final string of `Item is expected` per the custom message attribute supplied.

But if  try `validates_with`, instead...

```
 class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :parent

   validates_with TrivialValidator

 end

 class TrivialValidator

   def validate
      if record.item != "good"
        record.errors[:base] << "Bad item!"
      end
   end

 end
```

...Rails returns a `NameError - uninitialized constant Parent::Kid` error following not only an attempt to create (initial persist) user data, but also when even attempting to build the initial form.  Relevant bits from the controller:

```
def new
 @parent = Parent.new
 @parent.kids.new # NameError, validates_* methods called within
end

def create
 @parent = Parent.new(params[:parent])
 @parent.save # NameError, validates_* methods called within
end
```

The error suggests that somewhere during model name (and perhaps field name?) resolution for error message construction, something has run afoul. But why would it happen for some `validates_*` methods and not others?

Anybody else hit a wall with this?  Is there some ceremony needed here that I've left out in order to make this work, particularly regarding model names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours away, and returning fresh -- Was missing `require "Kid"` in `Parent` class.  Will edit.

Comment: That doesn't look right to me -- you shouldn't need to require another model.

Comment: Seemed weird to me, too.  But that did the trick.  Very possible that there is something else going outside of my dummied example that requires the "require Kid".